# Dockerfile COPY does not work with cloud-build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

I am able to build a Docker image with COPY locally but it does not work with cloud-build. My directory structure is the following:

```
Dockerfile.dev
.dockerignore
cloudbuild.yaml
script/
  - main.py
  - requirements.txt
  - entrypoint.sh
```

Dockerfile.dev contains the following command:

```
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY ["script/", "./"]
RUN pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt
```

I am able to build it locally by running

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.dev .
```

My cloudbuild.yaml looks like this:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/project/my_image', '-f', 'Dockerfile.dev', '.']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/project/my_image']

images: ['gcr.io/project/my_image']
```

Each time I run cloud-build I get an error that `requirements.txt` is not present as if it was not copied. Any fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY ["script/", "./"]
```

wishes to copy all the files in the local directory called `script` into the container directory `/opt/app`.

I believe the issue stems from the source definition being `script/`.  I was unable to find any semantics for a source ending with a `/`.  What I did find was:

> If `<src>` is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are
>   copied, including filesystem metadata.

What I'd suggest is testing with:

```
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY ["script", "./"]
```

and see if that makes a difference.

References:

- [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)