# Can't copy files with Dockerfile when using Cloud Build

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

I am planning to use Google Cloud build and cloud run. First I will test it manually, then I will adapt it based on code.

I have a simple html website, it uses php for the forms. I found a ready and official docker image and I'm running tests on it. I am successful in my tests at my local, but I am not getting successful results on google cloud build.

On Cloud Build Console, I added my git repo and trigger manually. They work very successfully. It triggers with automatic push, downloads my git repo and sees my Dockerfile.
But I fail in my "COPY" command given in the Dockerfile. Git can't find my files in my repo.

my purpose;

- download my git repo,
- Throwing my configuration files into php-fpm
- Throwing my configuration and website files into nginx

Google build is successfully downloading my git repo. It sees my Dockerfile. But it does not see my other files and directories in the same directory. Even though I cannot find the directories, I cannot copy my files with the "copy" command in the Dockerfile.

I tested "workdir" by setting many different directories, but it can't find my files in docker image.

Where could I be doing wrong?

The folder structure of my git repo;
(I only block the key file in .gitignore.)

```
root@3f1639b5e961:~# ls -l
.git
.gitignore
.key
Dockerfile 
website
configurations
additionals
```

Dockerfile running successfully in my local,

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm

USER root
WORKDIR /root/

mkdir /etc/nginx/website
mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
COPY ./website/* /etc/nginx/website/
COPY ./configurations/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./configurations/nginx/sites.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites.conf
COPY ./configurations/nginx/ssl/domain.crt /etc/nginx/ssl/
COPY ./configurations/nginx/ssl/domain.key /etc/nginx/ssl/

EXPOSE 80
```

Dockerfile tested with google build

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm

RUN ls /
RUN ls /root
RUN ls /tmp

WORKDIR /workspace

RUN pwd
RUN ls -lah

RUN mkdir /test
COPY .git/* /test/

RUN ls -lah /test/

EXPOSE 80
```

cloud build log;

```
... FETCHSOURCE ... Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/ From https://github.com/test-project/websites  * branch            da12067dc2db6ce22fa2f6dccefafe42f1546b2f -> FETCH_HEAD Updating files:  47% (3988/8473) ... Updating files: 100% (8473/8473), done. HEAD is now at da12067 changes.. BUILD Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.657GB

Step 1/12 : FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm latest: Pulling from richarvey/nginx-php-fpm f56be85fc22e: Already exists ... 4f4fb700ef54: Pulling fs layer ... 4f4fb700ef54: Waiting ec64d03a4b59: Verifying Checksum ec64d03a4b59: Download complete ... 6f118b82ab01: Pull complete 4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete Digest: sha256:4fbf5e62632e824cdf306cd32aba33728928289568f0d7ff9fffab9e4d304452 Status: Downloaded newer image for richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest 
---> c4dd6d93dbef


Step 2/12 : USER root  ---> Running in c201f8453a63 Removing intermediate container c201f8453a63  ---> cb452e958e03


Step 3/12 : WORKDIR /root/  ---> Running in 86b7a96556ae Removing intermediate container 86b7a96556ae  ---> e0794fec7a18


Step 4/12 : RUN ls /  ---> Running in 4d97f9498547 bin dev etc home lib media mnt opt proc root run sbin srv start.sh sys tmp usr var Removing intermediate container 4d97f9498547  ---> 9d8ac8e3675a


Step 5/12 : RUN ls /root  ---> Running in b878b5365429 Removing intermediate container b878b5365429  ---> 53fe225e10c2


Step 6/12 : RUN ls /tmp  ---> Running in 9550a78a33fb pear Removing intermediate container 9550a78a33fb  ---> 3dbf8d71c4fd


Step 7/12 : RUN pwd  ---> Running in 0bbee7d24109 /root Removing intermediate container 0bbee7d24109  ---> 882c8806f1e0


Step 8/12 : RUN ls -lah  ---> Running in 3f3044d6ac2b total 16K     drwx------    1 root     root        4.0K Apr 14 20:49 . drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K May  1 08:18 .. drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K Apr 14 20:44 .cache drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root    
4.0K Apr 14 20:49 .composer Removing intermediate container 3f3044d6ac2b  ---> e9bfc5cf5b67


Step 9/12 : RUN mkdir /build  ---> Running in 85e7ab92f034 Removing intermediate container 85e7ab92f034  ---> 6f3b958c1e9b


Step 10/12 : COPY .git/* /build/  ---> d4e3162b8107


Step 11/12 : RUN ls -lah /build/  ---> Running in de00358a4c5a total 1020K   drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K May  1 08:18 . drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K May  1 08:18 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         122 May  1 08:18 FETCH_HEAD
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         159 May  1 08:18 HEAD
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         478 May  1 08:17 applypatch-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         896 May  1 08:17 commit-msg.sample
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         233 May  1 08:18 config
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          73 May  1 08:17 description
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         240 May  1 08:17 exclude
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.6K May  1 08:17 fsmonitor-watchman.sample drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K May  1 08:18 heads
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      908.0K May  1 08:18 index drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K May  1 08:17 info drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root        4.0K May  1 08:18 pack
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         189 May  1 08:17 post-update.sample
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         424 May  1 08:17 pre-applypatch.sample
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        1.6K May  1 08:17 pre-commit.sample
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         416 May  1 08:17 pre-merge-commit.sample
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        1.3K May  1 08:17 pre-push.sample
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.8K May  1 08:17 pre-rebase.sample
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         544 May  1 08:17 pre-receive.sample
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        1.5K May  1 08:17 prepare-commit-msg.sample
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        2.7K May  1 08:17 push-to-checkout.sample drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root        4.0K May  1 08:18 refs
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          41 May  1 08:17 shallow drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K May  1 08:17 tags
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        3.6K May  1 08:17 update.sample Removing intermediate container de00358a4c5a  ---> 10ad3921c9b2


Step 12/12 : EXPOSE 80  ---> Running in 22f9a0f8ac32 Removing intermediate container 22f9a0f8ac32  ---> e05aacc1a054


Successfully built e05aacc1a054 Successfully tagged test-project:latest PUSH Pushing test-project:latest The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/test-project] 9258a4979331: Preparing ... 760a72e11ac9: Waiting denied: requested access to the resource is denied Pushing test-project:latest The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/test-project] be89f2fbe0bd: Preparing ...
```

I tried copying files first with Dockerfile. When I couldn't find the files, I tried searching the files and running different tests.

Comment: Can you share the docker build command that  you run? how do you run the Cloud Build job? What the content of your `.gitignore` file? Thanks

Comment: Actually I wrote above, I only have .key file in .gitignore. I don't use docker build command, google cloud build does it automatically when it receives push signal.cat .gitignore
.key

Comment: Ok, so what's your trigger config? What's your cloudbuild.yaml file?

Comment: Have a look at these stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283368/google-cloud-build-with-dockerfile-and-copy-files) ,[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57309458/dockerfile-copy-does-not-work-with-cloud-build) & [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70808037/dockerfile-copy-command-is-missing-a-single-file-when-using-gcloud-build)